# How to evalutate this exponential integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Is there an easy way to compute $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp(-x^2+2x)\mathrm{d}x$$
without using a computer package?

Comment: Try completing the square in the exponent.

Comment: $\exp(-x^2+2x)=\exp(-(x-1)^2)/e$, and substituting with $u=x-1$.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, I've just figured it out.

Comment: I judt ran into this. Found a solution in larsons problem solving through problems. Problem 1 ,4 ,4. He squares entire integral. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://math.la.asu.edu/~ifulman/spring13/mat194/problem-solving.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjop5ueza_cAhUJjFQKHVjmDwcQFjAAegQIABAB&usg=AOvVaw3ojecQy5DfCOW9Us_cozGx

Answer (score 6):

In general
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-(ax^2+bx)}\,dx&=\int_{x=0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)\right)\,dx\\
&=\exp\left(\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)\int_{x=0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2\right)\,dx\\
\end{align}
$$
Let $u=x+\frac{b}{2a}\;\rightarrow\;du=dx$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-(ax^2+bx)}\,dx&=\exp\left(\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)\int_{x=0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2\right)\,dx\\
&=\exp\left(\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)\int_{u=0}^\infty e^{-au^2}\,du.\\
\end{align}
$$
The last form integral is [Gaussian integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianIntegral.html) that equals to $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$. Hence
$$
\int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-(ax^2+bx)}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\exp\left(\frac{b^2}{4a}\right).
$$
In your case,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2+2x}\,dx&=2\int_0^\infty e^{-(x^2-2x)}\,dx\\
&=2\cdot\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1}}\exp\left(\frac{(-2)^2}{4\cdot1}\right)\\
&=e\sqrt{\pi}.
\end{align}
$$

---

$$\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}$$

Comment: I don't understand why the lower limit $x = 0$ does not change to $u = \frac{b}{2a}$ up on the change of variables. Indeed wolfram alpha shows your answer is not correct, likely due to this limit change?

Answer (score 3):

This is a [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral). In general you can use the formula
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-x^2+bx+c)\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\pi}~\exp(b^2/4+c)$. This formula, as suggested by Thomas, can be derived by completing the square in the exponent, and using $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-x^2)\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\pi}$.